# EF Running multiple queries - How can I change to use one query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm reviewing the amount of SQL queries that are being run per page load on my website.

The following method is running 1 SQL query PER entry within the Promotion table.

```
public IEnumerable<Promotion> GetPromotionsForStore(Store store)
{
    return Get().Where(p => p.ValidForStores.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(store.Id));
}
```

'ValidForStores' is a linking table which contains 'Promotion_Id' and 'Store_Id'. `Get()` basically ends up returning `IDbSet<Promotion>`.

If I was writing this as a normal SQL query, I could bring back all the promotions whilst still doing the store check but all with one query, however EF in this case runs the query below multiple times.

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent2].[StoreName] AS [StoreName], 
[Extent2].[IsDefault] AS [IsDefault], 
[Extent2].[ThemeName] AS [ThemeName], 
[Extent2].[AdminStore] AS [AdminStore], 
[Extent2].[UrlAffix] AS [UrlAffix], 
[Extent2].[WebsiteId] AS [WebsiteId], 
[Extent2].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId]
FROM  [dbo].[PromotionStore] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Store] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Store_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[Promotion_Id] = 41
```

Can anyone suggest a change that would mean a single query is used or am I expecting too much from EF?

Comment: What I can suggest you to fetch the data once from the DB and then perform your operation on it for each entry.

Comment: What is the return **type** of `Get()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `Get()` method is returning `IEnumerable<Promotion>`. In order to perform a single query, replace it with `IQueryable<Promotion>` equivalent, for instance

```
return context.Promotions.Where(...);
```

Comment: You're correct, I was using the wrong method on my service. `Get()` returns `IEnumerable<T>` but I have another one called `public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()` which I should be using.